# How can I add style tags to single file components in vue-jekyll?

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, jekyll

I've stumbled upon this repo [vue-jekyll](https://github.com/BryanSchuetz/vue-jekyll) which is so close to my needs..

It's missing one thing though, the ability to add `<style lang="scss" scoped>...</style>` to the single file components, example [here](https://github.com/BryanSchuetz/vue-jekyll/blob/master/components/app.vue).

It seems that the original dev is MIA on this project - so I'm reaching out to anyone that might know how to add this functionality to Webpack. The current [config](https://github.com/BryanSchuetz/vue-jekyll/blob/master/webpack.config.js) is as follows:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    //  OUR SOURCE FILE 
    jsSource: './js/source.js'
  },
  output: {
    //  OUR DESTINATION 
    filename: './js/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        use: 'json-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' // 'vue/dist/vue.common.js' for webpack 1
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas? :/